# Is it possible to get currency values returned by SkuDetails.getPrice()?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-billing, play-billing-library

I'm using **localizedPriceString** of Unity that actually calls **SkuDetails.getPrice()** of Android API. For correct displaying symbols of any currency would be great to know list of values can be returned by **SkuDetails.getPrice()** or **localizedPriceString**

Have not found the info in [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails#getPrice())

Is there any way to get it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: it returns a string you can use a loop to get a bunch of them.. otherwise your question is unclear

Comment: @BugFinder it returns a string according to locale specified on device.  For example "9,99грн" But I need to get аll currencies to be sure that font consists all of symbols can be returned

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to find Fonts and create Font Assets that support all signs used by Google Play Billing Services.
List of signs [From here](https://www.eurochange.co.uk/travel/tips/world-currency-abbreviations-symbols-and-codes-travel-money) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies)